# Elegant allocation of static readonly collection of strings

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a static `ReadOnlyCollection` with strings.

Is there any way to make this expression shorter or more elegant in some way?

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(
  new string[] {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
  }
);
```

I use this many times, but in different files.

Comment: you could omit the `string` in `new string[] {...` but not anything else...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(
  new [] {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to use `List<T>` with a collection initializer, and the [`AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorList = new List<String> {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
  }.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: @FrederikGheysels: Personally I'd be happy with either approach. I think I prefer this over explicitly creating an array and then wrapping it, but both will work equally well.

Comment: why do you prefer this (and seemingly most S.O. voters) over the List approach ?   I guess this approach has just a single new() instead of 2, which yeah, that seems better.  Is there something else ?

Comment: @orionelenzil: I don't know what you mean by "the List approach". (This *uses* a list.)

Comment: wups yes my mistake. I meant over the array approach.

Comment: @orionelenzil: Both work fine - I personally like the way this uses a fluent approach, so it's fairly easy to do something similar with a LINQ query etc without having the `new ReadOnlyCollection<T>` at the very start. But it really doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.AsReadOnly<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b.aspx) and `new[]` can infer the contents of the array:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorList = Array.AsReadOnly(
  new[] {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
  }
);
```

If you don't mind working with an interface, [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements several of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) including `IList<T>`:

```
public static readonly IList<string> ErrorList = Array.AsReadOnly(
  new[] {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
  }
);
```

Stylistically, I prefer to avoid multiple indentations for a single block:

```
public static readonly IList<string> ErrorList = Array.AsReadOnly(new[] {
  "string1",
  "string2",
  "string3",
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The most compact I think is:

```
using StringCol = ReadOnlyCollection<string>;
...
public static readonly StringCol ErrorList = new StringCol(
      new[]
      {
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
      });
```

The `using` directive is just here to reduce the amount of code in case you're using `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` a lot. If it's not the case, it won't reduce anything.

Comment: Picky: That's a using directive, not a using statement. But I don't think it's the most compact form available :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the pointing out the 'using' mistake, edited ;) And actually you're right it's not the shortest one here.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another possibility, by combining some of the great answers in this post.

Create a custom method with `params`:

```
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<String> CreateStringsReadOnlyCollection(params  string[] st){

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<String>(st);
    }
```

And then using it like:

```
 public readonly static ReadOnlyCollection<String> col = CreateStringsReadOnlyCollection("string1", "string2", "string3");
```